# Where and how to put in attachment into e-mail to send with python

Tags: python, email, email-attachments

I have recently learned how to get the latest photo taken with a webcam from a folder.
Now I would like to know where and how I put in the code so I always got the last photo from a folder.

This is my code to send the mail:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import userpass
import attachment
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

def send_a_picture():
    gmail_user = userpass.fromaddr
    gmail_pwd = userpass.password

    def mail(to, subject, text, attach):
       msg = MIMEMultipart()

       msg['From'] = userpass.fromaddr
       msg['To'] = userpass.toaddr
       msg['Subject'] = subject

       msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

       part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
       part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
       Encoders.encode_base64(part)
       part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
               'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
       msg.attach(part)

       mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.starttls()
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
       mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
       mailServer.close()

    mail(userpass.toaddr,
       "Hello from python!",
       "This is a email sent with python",
       "2017-01-17-19:47:44.jpg") # filename written into code


send_a_picture()
```

This code (above) works perfect when I specify a filename of a photo. 
But I would like to put in somewhere this code (below)so I can get the latest photo taken by the webcam.

```
def attach():

    import os
    import re

    files = os.listdir('/home/pi')
    jpgre = re.compile(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.jpg")
    jpgs = [s for s in files if jpgre.match(s)]

    jpgs.sort()

    file = jpgs[-1]

    print (file)



# Output:       attachment.attach()
#               2017-01-17-19:47:44.jpg
```

I tried a little after MKesper gave me a suggestion (trial and error).
There were two places I could put in the code (attach()) without error message. But there were no mail sent away.

I think I need some more help. Perhaps much more help.
I am actually still a beginner. Just trying to learn the hard way.
If I am lycky it's just a few rows of code left until success.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import userpass
import attachment
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

def send_a_picture():
    gmail_user = userpass.fromaddr
    gmail_pwd = userpass.password


**#tried the 'def attach()' in here.
# no error message but no mail.**


    def mail(to, subject, text, attach):
       msg = MIMEMultipart()

       msg['From'] = userpass.fromaddr
       msg['To'] = userpass.toaddr
       msg['Subject'] = subject

       msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

       part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
       part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
       Encoders.encode_base64(part)
       part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
               'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
       msg.attach(part)

       mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.starttls()
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
       mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
       mailServer.close()

#**tried the 'def attach()' in here too.
# No error message but no mail here either.**

    mail("sjodin.ulf@gmail.com",
       "Hello from python!",
       "This is a email sent with python",
       "2017-01-16-23:39:46.jpg") # with the filename it works


send_a_picture()
```

**I have found a solution.**

Perhaps not the best python code for this purpose. But it works for me.
And also a starting point from where I find  joy to develop my skill and coding.
Thanks for the tip with Python Email examples.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html?highlight=email%20examples
I used the third one that seemed to be the closest to what I was looking for.
This is the code I put together:

```
import smtplib      #Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import userpass     #for my 'user', 'to', 'from' adresses and password
import glob         #for the variable 'last'
import os           #for the variable 'last'

# Here are the email package modules we'll need
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

COMMASPACE = ', '

last = last_photo_taken = sorted(glob.glob("/home/pi/*.jpg"),key=os.path.getmtime)[-1] 
#this is the variable I learned in my first question in this forum:
#Python code to get (latest) file with timestamp as name to attach to email



# Create the container (outer) email message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Got the pyhon code working now. It has been a lot of Trial and Error.'
# me == the sender's email address
# family = the list of all recipients' email addresses
msg['From'] = userpass.fromaddr
msg['To'] = userpass.toaddr
msg.preamble = 'Image mail'

with open(last, 'rb') as fp:
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    msg.attach(img)


mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(userpass.fromaddr, userpass.password)
mailServer.sendmail(userpass.fromaddr, userpass.toaddr, msg.as_string())
mailServer.close()
```

Comment: Your "attach" function should be called get_latest_jpg and just return the value so it can be consumed in your calling function file_name = get_latest_jpg(). No need for nested functions, I guess.

Comment: Hello. I think I need a hint or two. Tried a little before (se new code above). It didńt work.

Comment: OK, try some tutorials / beginner books then. The [official Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) while not bad might still be too steep for you. Maybe [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/) would give you what you need. Oh, and don't bother about anything still teaching Python 2.